# Unable to create databases when running RavenDB on IISExpress

Tags: ravendb, iis-express

As the title says. (Cross post from the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/hxP3REWVMdg)

The iisexpress process is running as the currently logged in user, but I'm only getting Unauthorized error messages when trying to create databases.

Accessing /debug/user-info only gives the following message:
{"Remark":"Using anonymous user","AnonymousAreAdmins":false}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of Fitzchak Yitzchaki, I got the answer on the RavenDB mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/hxP3REWVMdg

The correct way of doing it was to set the `AnonymousAccess` setting in web.config to `Admin`:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>
```

The `AnonymousAccess` setting is not well documented, but it tells RavenDB how to treat anonymous users. In this instance, it treats all as admin and should therefore only be used in development. For production, it should be reset to the default value which is `All`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
            {
                Configuration = { Port = 8081 },
                DataDirectory = "~\\App_Data\\Raven",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
            };
store.Initialize();
```

Using "App_Data" will probably make it work for you.

Comment: I already had similar settings. I got the correct answer from the RavenDB mailing list.  
  
Thanks for helping though! :-)